# The reason for displaying an error when sending a post request by axios in React-native

Tags: react-native, axios

I wrote the following code for the post  request in react-native, but unfortunately, every time it displays an error message as follows
ERROR  Error making POST request: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500]

(I designed a form with the help of the child component, which I passed to it through props and callback function state, and then I wrote the request  post  to send data to the API backend .)

Can you help me solve my problem?

this  is my code  :

```
import  React ,{useState,useEffect}from "react";
import { Text,StyleSheet,View,Button,TouchableOpacity,ScrollView} from "react-native";
import FormInvoice from "../components/FormInvoice";
import DropdownComponent from "../components/DropdownComponent";
import Brouker from '../components/API/Brouker';
import  axios from  "axios";

// //********************function PostData***************** */




// useEffect(()=>{
//     PostData();
// },[]); 

// //**************************************************** */
function InvoiceSale (props){

//    ***************Difination of requierd state  ********************* */
    const [data ,setdata]=useState({

        NumberInvoice:'1',
        DateInvoice:'2',
        NameCustomer:'3',
        Name_product:'4',
        Unit_counter:'5',
        Amount_product:'6',
        price_per:'7',
        price_total:'8',
        Discount:'10'
    });
    const SendState=( 
            NumberInvoice,
            DateInvoice,
            NameCustomer,
            Name_product,
            Unit_counter,
            Amount_product,
            price_per ,
            price_total,
            Discount
            )=>{
       
            setdata({
                NumberInvoice ,
                DateInvoice ,
                NameCustomer ,
                Name_product,
                Unit_counter,
                Amount_product,
                price_per ,
                price_total ,
                Discount
         });
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        SendState();
    },[]); 
    // ************************************************* */
    const postData= async ()=>{
        const info =()=>({
            Number_invoice: "data.NumberInvoice",
            Date_create:"data.DateInvoice",
            Name_Customer:"data.NameCustomer" ,
            Unit_counter:"data.Unit_counter" ,
            Amount_product:"data.Amount_product" ,
            price_per :"data.price_per" ,
            price_total:" data.price_total",
        
        });
        try{
        const response=await axios.post("http://192.168.1.4:8000/Set_invoice_Sale",info
         )
            //    console.log(response.data);
               const data = await response.data;
               setdata(data);
               
       }catch (error) {
        console.error('Error making POST request:', error);
       }  
      
    };
    //************************************************* */
   

      //************************************************* */
    
    return(
<ScrollView >
        <View style={Styles.ViewCounter}> 
         <Text style={Styles.Title}> صورتحساب  فروش</Text>
         <View style={Styles.ViewManitor}>
           
             
            <Text >Lorem 21  </Text>
            <Text >Lorem 21  </Text>
            
             
        
                              
         </View>
            <View style={Styles.ViewInputs}>
                <FormInvoice  caption={"تاریخ :"} sendinfo={data.DateInvoice} sendSetState={SendState.DateInvoice} />
                <FormInvoice  caption={"شماره صورتحساب :"} sendinfo={data.NumberInvoice}  sendSetState={SendState.NumberInvoice} />
            </View>
            <View> 

                <DropdownComponent ></DropdownComponent>
                
            </View>
           
          
            <View>
            <DropdownComponent></DropdownComponent>
            </View>
            
            <View style={Styles.ViewInputs3}>
                <FormInvoice   caption={"مقدار :"}sendinfo={data.Amount_product} sendSetState={SendState.Amount_product} />
                <FormInvoice  caption={"واحد شمارش  :"} sendinfo={data.Unit_counter} sendSetState={SendState.Unit_counter}/>
                
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.ViewInputs3}>
                <FormInvoice  caption={"قیمت  کل  :"} sendinfo={data.price_total} sendSetState={SendState.price_total}/>
                <FormInvoice  caption={"قیمت فی  :"}sendinfo={data.price_per} sendSetState={SendState.price_per} />
                <FormInvoice  caption={" تخفیف  :"}sendinfo={data.Discount} sendSetState={SendState.Discount} />
                <FormInvoice  caption={"نام مشتری  :"}sendinfo={data.NameCustomer} sendSetState={SendState.NameCustomer} />
            </View>
        
            
            <View style={Styles.ViewInputs4}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.Button} onPress={postData}>
             <Text style={Styles.TextButton}> ذخیره</Text>
           
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.Button}>
            
             <Text style={Styles.TextButton}> ویرایش</Text>
            
            
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={Styles.Button}>
                   <Text style={Styles.TextButton}> پاک کردن</Text>
            
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
            </View>
        
        </View>
       
        </ScrollView>
        
    )
};


export default InvoiceSale;
```

Comment: Maybe you can share server code for  understanding the problem better.

Comment: What looks off is, that you pass `info` as a second parameter to your post request, which is declared as a function. You can try declaring `info` as a simple object. In the assignment like this `Number_invoice: "data.NumberInvoice"` you are simply assigning a string. I would guess you want to have `Number_invoice: data.NumberInvoice` instead